# Social media feed generation using redis

Tags: postgresql, redis, architecture, nestjs, software-design

Currently working on a project with the stack of NestJS+Postgres on the backend side and a flutter app which is a social media app.

The backend is already written to allow users to sign up, login using mfa code, view their profile and update it, search for other users , also search for channels.

Users are able to create their own channels.

Also users can create posts as a personal post or from within the channel (same post entity, same creator id, but there's an extra field on the posts table called 'channel_id')

Users are able to follow both users and channels , I have a relationship table called followers which is a belongs to many relationship table with:

followableId, followableType (channel/user), followerId

This way I can save all users and channels followers in one table.

I have redis integrated but have not used it yet.

All queries are currently always reading from the DB, whether it's user search. Followers search or channels search.

What would be the best way to store those query results in redis? Considering I have user data that can be changed quite frequently (meaning avatar,name, followers count etc ) these are all displayed in the search results grid , so if 1 user follows the same user and both search for that user in their followers list (I need that user data to be updated instantly) using some sort of caching mechanism.

Now for the feed part I have yet touched it , looking for the best way to approach this.
I've got a posts table, which contains:

Id, title, subheading, media_1, content, media_2., creator_id, channel_id..etc...etc

Whats the best way to build a feed item list for users ? Say a user follows a channel and a new post is created in that channel ( all users who follow the channel need their feed updated with that post) same goes for an individual post which is not related to a channel , but to a specific user, if I unfollow a user or channel my feed needs to omit those posts as I have stopped following that entity.

What's the best approach here?

I haven't tried yet to implement the social media feed, looking for possible solutions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: seems you need grid package like flutter super grid: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_super_grid